# Old users can't login after changing password validation rule

Tags: regex, symfony, fosuserbundle

i am using symfony 2 to build a web platform for my company. Recently, i have changed the validation rule inside my User entity by adding the following code:

```
/**
* @Assert\Regex(
*     pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,127}$/",
*     message="edit.personnal_info.udpate.message.password_info_regex",
*     groups={"registration"}
* )
*/
protected $plainPassword;
```

After this change, all my old created users can't login anymore. Just new users, with valid password can get connected.

I don't want to change all old passwords. So, if there is a way to skip validation rules while login, it will be OK.

Ps: i'm using FOSUserBundle.

Comment: You will need to specify the validation group to use while logging in: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html Gave up using FOSUserBundle a long time ago so I cannot provide more details.

Comment: Are you sure you only changed the validation rule for registration? This rule has nothing to login.

Comment: Yes @KamilAdryjanek, i'm sure because it works when i remove the Assert annotation

Comment: Ok, wchich version of `FOSUserBundle` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution if your issue is that old users used shorter passwords and you want to support them until next password change**

Instead of adding this constrain to entity you could add it to your registration and change password forms

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new Regex([
                    'pattern' => '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,127}$/'
                ]),
                new NotBlank()
            ]
        ]);
}
```

this way you can enforce new password policy for new users without breaking logic for old users.